XML TRANSFORM: Nested array not resulting in correct order for child values
I want to transform a complex json to a expected json structure in Azure Logic App. I have converted the input json to xml and created XSLT file to apply the transformation. Using XML Transform action from Logic App, I tried converting it to expected xml format and convert back the same to json. I encountered issue with nested arrays which are not picking up correct child value and I can see it has picked up random child of the parent array. I really need to fix this.
I'm exploring doing it with xsl:apply-templates meanwhile looking for error resolution in this.
what I tried:
Input xml:
{
  "?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "utf-8"
  },
  "Model": {
    "EmpDetails": {
      "Emp": [
        {
          "EmpId": "32370",
          "Job": {
            "EmpJob": {
               "JobId": "2121470-2"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "EmpId": "30413",
          "Job": {
            "EmpJob": {
               "JobId": "2121470"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "EmpId": "32372",
          "Job": {
            "EmpJob": {
               "JobId": "2121470-4"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "EmpId": "32371",
          "Job": {
            "EmpJob": {
               "JobId": "2121470-3"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

XSL File:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <model>
            <employmentDetails>
                <xsl:for-each select="/Model/EmpDetails">
                    <employments>
                        <employmentId>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Emp/EmpId"/>
                        </employmentId>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Job">
                            <jobs>
                                <jobUserId>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="EmpJob/JobId"/>
                                </jobUserId>
                            </jobs>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </employments>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </employmentDetails>
        </model>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output Result I'm Getting: jobUserId is mostly populated random and changes everytime.
{
    "employmentDetails": {
        "employments": [
            {
                "EmpId": "32370",
                "jobs": {
                    "jobUserId": "2121470-2"
                }
            },
            {
                "EmpId": "30413",
                "jobs": {
                    "jobUserId": "2121470-2"
                }
            },
            {
                "EmpId": "32372",
                "jobs": {
                    "jobUserId": "2121470-4"
                }
            },
            {
                "EmpId": "32371",
                "jobs": {
                    "jobUserId": "2121470-4"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Output Result expected:
{
    "employmentDetails": {
        "employments": [
            {
                "EmpId": "32370",
                "jobs": {
                    "jobUserId": "2121470-2"
                }
            },
            {
                "EmpId": "30413",
                "jobs": {
                    "jobUserId": "2121470"
                }
            },
            {
                "EmpId": "32372",
                "jobs": {
                    "jobUserId": "2121470-4"
                }
            },
            {
                "EmpId": "32371",
                "jobs": {
                    "jobUserId": "2121470-3"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}


I think we need to see the XML that the JSON-to-XML converter is producing.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you want to transform a complex JSON to a different JSON, perhaps you can do it easier without converting it to XML and utilizing XSLT. But for that, you would have to provide the source JSON and the end JSON result that you are expecting.

You need to correct XSL file to as below to map the correct EmpId to JobId.
Iterate over /Model/EmpDetails/Emp instead of /Model/EmpDetails.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <model>
            <employmentDetails>
                <xsl:for-each select="/Model/EmpDetails/Emp">
                    <employments>
                        <employmentId>
                            <xsl:value-of select="EmpId"/>
                        </employmentId>
                        <jobs>
                            <jobUserId>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Job/EmpJob/JobId"/>
                            </jobUserId>
                        </jobs>
                    </employments>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </employmentDetails>
        </model>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

I am using below workflow to get the expected output as you mentioned you are using Transform XML action but there are multiple ways and actions available in logic app to get the desired result.



